How to set a non-static field in java reflection?
I tried to use java reflection to set a non-static field value of class, but got the "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"
if I add the "static" modifier for this field. All codes will pass without any exception.
Here is my codes:
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections("abc.test", new SubTypesScanner(false));
        Set<Class<?>> classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
        for (Class clazz : classes) {
            try {
                Optional<Field> optional = Arrays.stream(clazz.getDeclaredFields())
                        .filter(f -> VariableResolver.class.isAssignableFrom(f.getType()))
                        .findFirst();
                if (!optional.isPresent()) {
                    continue;
                }

                Field field = optional.get();
                field.setAccessible(true);
                field.set(clazz, new DefaultVariableResolver());
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

Here is the class file and the field.
public class TestClass {
    VariableResolver resolver;  //The code can only pass if I add 'static' modifier for this field.

    public void method(){
        String a = resolver.get("test");
    }
}

The exception is:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set test.util.VariableResolver field test.TestClass.resolver to java.lang.Class
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:75)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:799)


Which instance of TestClass do you want to set resolver?

Hi, I am using the Cucumber + Serenity framework. The instance will be created by the framework. I needn't create the instance in my codes.

Well you need to have access to that instance before you can set one of its fields. field.set(thatInstance, new DefaultVariableResolver());

Hi, Can you give more details on how to "have access to that instance"?  Thank you.

Only you can know that. Only you can know how your framework makes it available to you.

You can create an instance by calling a constructor, for example with reflection.
